# Use a method type while still inferring arguments

Tags: typescript

## Use Case

I have a class that is constructed by passing in a list of methods and then lets you call those methods through the class (the class adds some additional functionality). These methods have the class (Foo) bound as their context when being called. So I have a `FooMethod` type.

```js
class Foo {
  public constructor(methods) {}
}

const myMethod: FooMethod<number> = function(value: number): number {
  return value
}

const myMethods = [myMethod]

const foo = new Foo(myMethods)

type FooMethod<T> = (this: typeof foo, ...args: any[]) => T

type MyMethodParameters = Parameters<typeof myMethod> // any[]
```

## Issue

By adding the type `FooMethod<number>` to the `myMethod` const. I can no longer get the type of the arguments for the function by doing `Parameters<typeof myMethod>`

## Question

Is there a way to have the `FooMethod` type still infer the arguments? I'd like to be able to do `Parameters<typeof myMethod>` and still get `[number]`

Comment: is there any reason you need the explicit  type annotation of `: FooMethod<number> `? removing it would give you `[value: number]`

Comment: And where are you looking to utilise this `FooMethod` type? im not sure this even  needs explicitly declaring

Comment: using the `FooMethod` type provides a type for `this` within the context of the function

Comment: Without `FooMethod` you don't get the type for `this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in your `type FooMethod<T>` you declare the rest parameter as being any[].

You could add the arguments as a generic to your type:

```js
type FooMethodNew<Args extends any[], ReturnValue> = (this: typeof foo, ...args: Args) => ReturnValue
```

But may be redundant/verbose in practice

```js
const myMethodNew: FooMethodNew<[value: number], number> = function(value: number): number {...}
```

Instead, you can use a helper function to help leverage the inferencing powers of functions

```js
const fooMethodBuilder = <Args extends any[], ReturnValue>(func: FooMethodNew<Args, ReturnValue>) {
    return func
}

const myMethodBuilt = fooMethodBuilder(function(value: number): number {
    console.log(this)
    return value
})

type MyMethodParameters3 = Parameters<typeof myMethodBuilt> // [value: number]
```

[View this on TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mq1eRm)

Comment: Nice, the combination of using a generic for the method type and a generic in the builder method gives me the types I want without having to be explicit. Thank you!

Comment: Realizing that the helper function breaks the types if the const it creates is exported. Which I believe is because `FooMethod` has `typeof foo` and `foo` accepts the methods in its constructor. So using the helper function makes the inference recursive. Just using the method type works fine though. Declaring the arguments explicitly in the type declaration isn't a big deal. Though I was excited that the helper method would let me skip that.